# Code to exclude a zip file

Tags: vba

I have the following code that will list reports (files and folders) from a directory.
There is one type I would like excluded from the listing:  `Zip` folders.

Wondering how and where to include this exclusion?

```vb
Dim iRow

Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 2
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("F1"), Range("F2"))
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        iCol = 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to determine the file extension of the current file.
Therefore we can search the first `.` (dot) from the right side in a filename:

```
InStrRev(myFile.Name, ".") 'position of the first dot
```

with this position we can extract the file extension from the filename:

```
LCase$(Right$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - InStrRev(myFile.Name, ".")))
'LCase is used to transform the extension to lower case letters so it is case insensitive
```

So we can easily exclude all `zip` files from the listing by checking the file extension:

```
If LCase$(Right$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - InStrRev(myFile.Name, "."))) <> "zip" Then
     'file is no zip file
End If
```

---

- I also recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare all variable types correctly, so you don't run into any type issues.
- Also don't use `On Error Resume Next`, that's a very bad practice. It makes you blind for any error messages, but the errors still occur, you just don't see them. Implement a proper error handling instead, that shows a message if an error occurs, so we at least know that something went wrong.
- Don't use `Call` statement it's deprecated and not needed anymore.

So we end up with something like this:

```
Option Explicit 'force variable declare

Public iRow As Long 'always declare a type

Public Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 2
    ListMyFiles "C:\Temp", False 'don't use call
End Sub

Public Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean) 'declare types for variables to avoid odd behaviors
    Dim MyObject As FileSystemObject 'declare ALL variables and specify a type
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim mySource As Folder
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)

    Dim iCol As Long: iCol = 1 'starting column

    'On Error Resume Next 'don't use this or you are blind! use a proper error handling if needed
    Dim myFile As File
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        If LCase$(Right$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - InStrRev(myFile.Name, "."))) <> "zip" Then 'exclude zip file extensions
            Cells(iRow, iCol + 0).Value = myFile.Path 'count iCol from start value (reduces code)
            Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Value = myFile.Name
            Cells(iRow, iCol + 2).Value = myFile.Size
            Cells(iRow, iCol + 3).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next myFile

    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        Dim mySubFolder As Folder
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            ListMyFiles mySubFolder.Path, True 'don't use call
        Next mySubFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Edit:
According to *@Ahmed Abdelhameed*s comment you can also use

```
LCase$(MyObject.GetExtensionName(myFile.Path))
```

instead of

```
LCase$(Right$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - InStrRev(myFile.Name, ".")))
```

to retrieve the file extension from a file. `GetExtensionName` is even a little faster.

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. Just a small note: `FileSystemObject` has a `GetExtensionName()` method, so I would use that.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes of course, added it. It's even a little faster.